# Is 'color' countable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

In the Collins, the word "color" itself is countable. In one article which talks about countable and uncountable, the author says "colors" is uncountable. I think the "colors" in the article means specific color such as red, yellow. These words are uncountable.
Here comes my question. If I want to ask what's the color of two dogs, Which one is right, color or colors?
Please help.

Comment: If one were to say "The words brought color to her face", "color" would be used as an uncountable.  Ie, the plural would be "The words brought color to their faces."

Comment: I can't find a marking of the word _color/colour_ as either countable or non-countable in the [Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colour). It would be best to link to the dictionary you used (or cite it) and give the quote.  [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/colour_1) on the other hand gives a far more detailed analysis of the usages. But MorganFR's answer is perfectly tailored to fit your question, and shows that it's usages, not nouns, that are count or non-count.

Comment: I made a big mistake! Yesterday, I looked up the word via an APP which is a translated edition of Collins.  I thought I got the whole idea about the word. Just now I took your advice and realized the APP doesn't keep the whole content. :(  I'll never use that APP again.  Thank you, Edwin Ashworth. Without you, who knows when I gonna find this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "What is the color of those two dogs?"

Both dogs have the same color.

> "What color are those two dogs?"

Both can have a different color, but most likely one color each.

> "What colors are those two dogs?"

Both dogs may have the same colors or different colors, but they have several colors each, or at least one of them does.

> "What are the colors of those two dogs?"

Both dogs can have the same multiple colors or each be of (a) different color(s).

> "Leaves are different **shades of brown and red** in the fall."
>
> "The **reds and browns** of the woods in the fall."

As for the names of the colors themselves, they can be [countable and uncountable](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/red_2). To differentiate them, you can use "shades" for instance.